# Можно ли на Python создать несколько потоков, имея один в качестве шаблона?

Tags: python, многопоточность, proxy, threading

Я пишу программу на Python для массовой проверки прокси-адресов на их работоспособность.

Но возникла одна проблема. Зная о возможностях библиотеки ["threading"](https://pypi.org/project/threaded/), я не могу реализовать следующую вещь: "искусственно" **создать несколько потоков из одного, при этом в них выполняется одна и та же задача.**

*В случае чего, пытаюсь это реализовать в угоду меньшего размера конечного файла с кодом.*

Как реализовать подобное?

*Изменено*

Код на данный момент

```
from colored import Fore, Back, Style
from proxy_checking import ProxyChecker
import os
import threading

proxy_checker = ProxyChecker()
#print(proxy_checker.check_proxy('128.2.242.17:8080'))

os.system('cls')
os.system('chcp 65001>nul')

print('FireProxyCheck' + '\033[39m')
print()
print(f'{Fore.RGB(255, 96, 96)}1) Check proxy from file')
print(f'{Fore.RGB(255, 96, 96)}2) Check proxy from input')
print(f'{Fore.RGB(255, 96, 96)}3) Exit')

choice = int(input(f'{Fore.RGB(255, 96, 96)}Your choice? '))
```

Comment: Покажите вашу попытку для начала.

Comment: Многопоточность используется для ускорения обработки, а не для экономии кода. Код от неё наоборот разбухает. И насчёт одной задачи не совсем понятно. Сформулируйте чётко что у вас есть, какой код (покажите его в вопросе) и что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте библиотеку multitasking. Вам ее хватит. По сути вы просто перед функцией которая должна выполнятся в нескольких потоках ставите деколатор и потом через цикл запускаете нужное вам количество потоков.